# What did the communal korbanot on Yom Kippur atone for?

Tags: yom-kippur, repentance-teshuvah, korban

The torah tells us to bring korbanot to atone for certain sins (when bringing korbanot is possible).  In *addition*, on Yom Kippur the kohein gadol offers korbanot to atone for the whole people.  What sins does that cover?

- Perhaps this covers unknown sins, for which the transgressor never brought a korban because he didn't know he'd transgressed.  (I remember learning this somewhere but don't know where.  It also seems consistent with parts of the Yom Kippur liturgy today (as I've experienced it), where we confess for sins known and unknown.)
- Perhaps this covers people who ought to have brought korbanot but didn't.
- Or perhaps, even if everybody knew about all sins and brought all required korbanot, this is a necessary additional step -- just like a korban alone doesn't atone if you don't also make reparations, maybe reparations + that korban doesn't atone until you also have the communal offering on Yom Kippur?

So, what atonement do the Yom Kippur korbanot effect?

Answer (score 2):

> יש בה ידיעה בתחלה ואין בה ידיעה בסוף שעיר הנעשה בפנים ויום הכפורים תולה עד שיודע לו ויביא בעולה ויורד אין בה ידיעה בתחלה אבל יש בה ידיעה בסוף שעיר הנעשה בחוץ ויום הכפורים מכפר ... ר' מאיר אומר כל השעירין כפרתן שוה על טומאת מקדש וקדשיו ... ר"ש אומר ... של יום הכפורים מכפר על שאין בה ידיעה בתחלה אבל יש בה ידיעה בסוף ... ר"ש בן יהודה אומר ... של יום הכפורים שהן מכפרין על הטהור שאכל את הטמא ועל שאין בה ידיעה לא בתחלה ולא בסוף ועל שאין בה ידיעה בתחלה אבל יש בה ידיעה בסוף ... על שאר עבירות שבתורה הקלות והחמורות הזדונות והשגגות הודע ולא הודע עשה ולא תעשה כריתות ומיתות בית דין שעיר המשתלח מכפר אחד ישראלים ואחד כהנים ואחד כהן משוח מה בין ישראלים לכהנים ולכהן משוח אלא שהפר מכפר על הכהנים על טומאת מקדש וקדשיו ר"ש אומר כשם שדם השעיר הנעשה בפנים מכפר על ישראל כך דם הפר מכפר על הכהנים כשם שוידויו של  שעיר המשתלח מכפר על ישראל כך וידויו של פר מכפר על הכהנים

The above is a paraphrase of the first mishna if Shavuot. Translation:

(Until specified, this mishna is about violations of sanctity, as in eating קדשים  and going into the בית המקדש, while טמא.) If there was knowledge at the beginning but not the end, the שעיר הנעשה בפנים and the day of יום הכיפורים suspend the sin until he finds out and brings a קרבן עולה ויורד. If there was knowledge at the end but not the beginning, the שעיר הנעשה בפנים and the day of יום כיפור atone. R' Meir says, all שעירים are specifically for [violations of prohibitions] of טומאת מקדש וקדשיו. R' Shimon says, the שעיר of יו''כ is for knowledge at the end but not the beginning. R' Shimon ben Yehuda says, that of יו''כ atones for someone who is טהור who ate something [קדוש] that is טמא, as well as on on someone who had no knowledge at all, and on one who had knowledge at the end but not the beginning. All other sins in the תורה, severe or not, intentional or not, known or not, positive or negative, excommunication and capital crimes, the "scapegoat" atones, for Israelites, priests, and the high priest, except that the bull atones for the priests who transgressed the purity of the קודש and the קדשים. R' Shimon says, just as the blood of the  הנעשה בפנים שעיר atones for Israelites, so to the blood of the bull atones for the priests. Just as the confession on the "scapegoat" atones for Israelite, so to the confession on the bull atones for priests.

Fot a more elucidated explanation, see the מפרשי המשניות on the first mishna of Shavuot, or this link: [Soncino in English, PDF](http://www.halakhah.com/rst/nezikin/37a%20-%20Shevuos%20-%202a-28b.pdf).